# Batch file for counting the files with same initial name and moving them

Tags: batch-file

Is it possible to do this?
In a folder i have files with same initial names

Example:

```
Main folder
   -Quest2323231.txt  
     Quest2343434.txt  
     Quest2343435.txt   
     Fund103.txt  
    Fund102.txt
```

I have a config file (abc.config) in which i have name of file on which i need to count and move them . If the count is more than 2 then i need to move them.
In this case for e g I need to find files which have name as 'Quest'
Appreciate you help on this.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
  setlocal enableextensions
  set "number="
  for /f "tokens=1" %%a in (
    'dir /a-d /-c "c:\mainfolder\quest*" 2^>nul^|findstr /b /c:"  "'
  ) do if not defined number set "number=%%a"
  if not defined number set "number=0"

  echo %number%
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested: This expects text in the first line of abc.config which is the file information such as `Quest` in the example and if there are more than `2 matching files` in the `source folder` then it will `echo` a `move` command to move them to the `target folder`.

Change `*%file%*` to `%file%*` in two places if you want to match only the start of the filename.

Remove the `echo` to actually perform the move commands.

```
@echo off
set "source=c:\mainfolder"
set "target=d:\target\folder"
set /p "file=" < "abc.config"

for /f %%a in ('dir /b /a-d "%source%\*%file%*" ^|find /i "%file%" 2^>nul^|find /c /v "" ') do set "number=%%a"
if %number% GTR 2 for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d "%source%\*%file%*" ^|find /i "%file%" ') do (
   echo move "%source%\%%a" "%target%"
)
pause
```